# form of function is incorrect

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I have a function, everyNth that takes a list created by the user, as well as a number i, and creates a new list with every multiple of i found in the user created list. For example, if I entered

```
everyNth[1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6] 3;;
```

the result is

```
int list = [3; 6]
```

this function is currently in the form of

```
int list-> int -> int list
```

and I need it to be

```
('a list) -> int -> ('a list)
```

I will paste the code below this. I am very new to ocaml so any suggestions or tips would be appreciated!

```
let everyNth a i = 
  let rec aux = function
    |[]->[]
    |h :: t -> if h mod i = 0 then h::aux t else aux t in aux a;;
```

Comment: `mod` is a function that takes two ints and returns an int. So if you write `h mod i` you are saying that `h` is an int. So this function will work only for lists of ints. As I understand it (from your description of the desired type of the function), you want to make a list based on the indices (the positions) of the values in the original list. This code is making a test based on the values themselves, not their positions.

Comment: what is the best way to go about doing that? could I increase an int value every iteration of aux, and compare that value with the given value i?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I would suggest.

Comment: How would i increment the int value?

Comment: I will write an answer, it's too long for this comment area.

Answer (score 1):

In essence you want to have a value that tracks your position as you process the list. When processing the first element, the value is 1. Then it's 2 for the next element and so on. In functional programming, however, there's no way to modify the value of a variable. So you can't imagine having a single value that you increment. Instead you should imagine having a function parameter that is 1 larger for each recursive call.

Here is a function that returns the 4th element of a list using this technique:

```
let fourth list =
    let rec aux i l =
        match l with
        | [] -> failwith "List too short"
        | h :: t -> if i = 4 then h else aux (i + 1) t
    in
    aux 1 list
```

(In fact OCaml is a multi-paradigm language and you can have mutable variables whose value can be changed. But that is something to learn later on I think.)

Answer (score 0):

A way of looking at this is to break it down into smaller problems.

**Step 1:** You attach an index to each element in the list.

```
let index lst =
  let rec aux lst i =
    match lst with
    | [] -> []
    | x::xs -> (x, i) :: aux xs (i+1)
  in
  aux lst 0
```

```
# index [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6];;
- : (int * int) list = [(1, 0); (2, 1); (3, 2); (4, 3); (5, 4); (6, 5)]
```

**Step 2:** You then want to filter out only the elements at every third index.

```
let rec thirds lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> []
  | (_, i as x)::xs when (i+1) mod 3 = 0 -> x :: thirds xs
  | _::xs -> thirds xs
```

```
# index [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6] |> thirds;;
- : (int * int) list = [(3, 2); (6, 5)]
```

**Step 3:** Then you want to extract just the first element of each.

```
let rec extract_firsts lst =
  match lst with 
  | [] -> []
  | (x, _)::xs -> x :: extract_firsts xs
```

```
# index [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6] |> thirds |> extract_firsts;;
- : int list = [3; 6]
```

Of course, all of these are just reimplementations of standard library functions.

```
# let thirds lst =
    lst
    |> List.mapi (fun i x -> (x, i))
    |> List.filter (fun (_, i) -> (i+1) mod 3 = 0)
    |> List.map fst;;
val thirds : 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>
# thirds [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6];;
- : int list = [3; 6]
```

Or using `List.filter_map`:

```
# let thirds lst =
    lst
    |> List.mapi (fun i x -> (x, i))
    |> List.filter_map (fun (x, i) -> if (i+1) mod 3 = 0 then Some x else None);;
val thirds : 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>
# thirds [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6];;
- : int list = [3; 6]
```

Or if we want to be lazy and not generate a whole new list in that first step we can use sequences.

```
# let thirds lst =
    lst
    |> List.to_seq 
    |> Seq.mapi (fun i x -> (x, i))
    |> Seq.filter_map (fun (x, i) -> if (i+1) mod 3 = 0 then Some x else None)
    |> List.of_seq;;
val thirds : 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>
```